# How to decompose an equation into tangential and normal components?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, vectors

[image]

Not sure what this question is asking. I know how to find T and N as shown below:

[image]

My problem is finding the "number". It says to give your answer to three decimal places. But I have no clue how they get a number when given a vector/magnitude. Even if I plug in 2, it would still be a vector/magnitude. For example, it would look like this:
$$\frac{<3,\:4,\:5>}{3}$$

How would I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: The numbers asked are aT and aN

Comment: @trula yea how would I find that. I can find T, but like. Idk

Comment: You have $(a_1, a_2, a_3) = a_{\bf T} (T_1, T_2, T_3) + a_{\bf N} (N_1, N_2, N_3)$ where each vector is known. Now you solve for $a_{\bf T}, a_{\bf N}$, component-wise.

Comment: @player3236 sorry, I'm still not understanding that. I can get to that position. then what do you mean by solve component-wise?

Comment: Solve:

$$\begin{cases}a_1=a_{\bf T} T_1 + a_{\bf N} N_1\\a_2=a_{\bf T} T_2 + a_{\bf N} N_2\\a_3=a_{\bf T} T_3 + a_{\bf N} N_3\end{cases}$$

Comment: @player3236 hmm ok i think i get it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just find the vectors $\mathbf{T}(2)$ and $\mathbf{N}(2)$.

They want you to find the scalars $c_1, c_2$ so that $\mathbf{r}(2) = c_1\mathbf{T}(2) + c_2\mathbf{N}(2)$.

As a hint, what happens if you take the dot product of both sides with $\mathbf{T}(2)$, given that $\mathbf{T}(2)$ and $\mathbf{N}(2)$ are perpendicular? Ditto with $\mathbf{N}(2)$?

Comment: thank you for this. i will try r(2) = that stuff and ill let u know how it goes